# How to integrate JQuery Ajax POST/GET to Spring MVC

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, spring-mvc, jdbctemplate

Hello guys I'm new in Jquery and ajax, I don't know how to figure out this blockage any help will be appreciated. I want to dynamically implement a drop down box using JQuery ajax, i have seen so many example out. I tested one implementation which work perfectly when I run it. But I tried to apply the same code to my Spring MVC project and added the same libraries to my projecbut it is not working.
- I am using Alert for debugging As you will see in my Js code, I am able to enter the Js `getCategoryForSelectedProduct()` method but that's all it is not calling the method in the Rest controller thought the url is correct (it is the same url in fact the same code i used in the example I found on this url: [link to Spring MVC example][1] I have added a new link to that example that work similarly as Example1 and not in my Spring MVC Project. I suspect that it is a configuration or libraries mismatch issues but I am lost.

I am sure that the problem lies on the fact that `$ajax()` post request is not accessing the `@ResController`

I want to dynamically populate Category list base on choosen product

I am such able to enter the Js after setecing a particular product But ajax post request is not working.

## NavigationController.java

```
    @Autowired
    IPerformanceDao performanceDao;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/loadReport", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String ManageIntroducer(ModelMap modelMap) {

            ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();

            Introducer introducer = new Introducer();
            Product product = new Product();

            Category category = new Category();
            SubCategory subCategory = new SubCategory();
            int affiliateId = 1;
            List<Product> lstprd = performanceDao.getAllProducts(affiliateId);
            List<Category> lstctg = performanceDao.getAllCategoriesByProductId(product.getProductId());
            List<SubCategory> sbctglst = performanceDao.getAllSubCategoriesByCategoryId(1);
            List<Introducer> itrdclst = performanceDao.getAllIntroducers(affiliateId);

            modelMap.addAttribute("productEntity", product);
            modelMap.addAttribute("introducerEntity", introducer);
            modelMap.addAttribute("categoryEntity", category);
            modelMap.addAttribute("subCategoryEntity", subCategory);

            modelMap.put("introducerList", itrdclst);
            modelMap.put("productList", lstprd);
            modelMap.put("SubCategoryList", sbctglst);
            modelMap.put("CategoryList", lstctg);

            mv = new ModelAndView("loadReport", "command", product);

            return "loadReport";
        }
```

## CategoryRestController.java

```
     @RestController
        @RequestMapping("/dropdown")
        public class CategoryRestController {

        @Autowired
        private CategoryService categoryService;

        @RequestMapping(value = "getCategoryForSelectedProduct", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers="Content-Type=application/json")
        public @ResponseBody List<String> getCitiesForSelectedState(@RequestParam(value = "productName", required = true) String productName) {
            System.out.print("in getcategories method with productId : "+productName);
            List<String> ctgList = new ArrayList<String>();
            ctgList.add("Select Category");

            ctgList.addAll(categoryService.getAllCategoriesByProductName(productName));

            return ctgList;
        }
```

## loadReport.jsp

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
    <%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
    <%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
    enter <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/resouces/css/style.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Manage Introducer</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table width="100%" id="loanTable">
    <tr>
    <td align="right">  
    <!-- include top right menu jsp -->   
    <jsp:include page="topRightMenu.jsp" />
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>      
    <!-- content for main body -->
    <table width="100%">
    <tr>
    <td width="20%" valign="top"> 
    <!-- left menu -->
    <jsp:include page="leftMenu.jsp" />
    </td>
    <td width="80%" valign="top"> 
    <!--main body -->
    <div id="mainBody">
    <table border="0" width="100%" height="600">

    <tr><td valign="top"> 

    <div class="springajax" style="width:450px; height:150px;">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td >AJAX Cascading </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Select Product</td>
                <td>
                    <select name="product" id="product" onblur="getCategoryForSelectedProduct()">
                        <option value="Select Product">Select Product</option>
                        <c:forEach items="${productList}" var="p">
                            <option value="${p.productName}">${p.productName}</option>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Select Category</td>
                <td>
                    <select id="category" name="category">
                        <option value="Select Category">Select Category</option>
                    </select>
                    <div id="loading"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table><br>
    </div>

    <div align="center">
        <form:form modelAttribute="introducerEntity" method="post" action="saveIntroducer" commandName="introducerEntity"> 
       <font color="red"> ${message} </font>
       <table >

        <tr>
             <td><form:label path="subCategoryId">SubCategory Name:</form:label></td>
                <td>
                   <form:select path="subCategoryId">
                        <form:options items="${SubCategoryList}" itemLabel="subCategoryName" itemValue="id" />
                   </form:select>
                </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
             <td><form:label path="agencyId">Agency:</form:label></td>
             <td>
                        <form:select path="agencyId">
                        <form:options items="${agencyList}" itemLabel="Name" itemValue="Id" />
                        </form:select>
                        <td><form:hidden  path="Id" /></td>

          </tr>

          <tr>
             <td><form:label path="firstName">First Name</form:label></td>
             <td><form:input path="firstName" />
          </tr>  
          <tr>
             <td><form:label path="lastName">Last Name</form:label></td>
             <td><form:input path="lastName" />
             <form:hidden path="affiliateId" /></td>
          </tr>  
           <tr>
             <td><form:label path="active">is Active ?</form:label></td>
             <td><form:checkbox path="active" /></td>
          </tr> 
          <tr>
          <td></td>
             <td >
                <input class="tag-btn " type="submit" value="Add"/>
             </td>
          </tr>
       </table>
       </form:form>
      </div> 


    <div id="Entitylist" align="center" >
            <table class="table1">
                <tr>
                    <th>Id</th><th>FirstName</th><th>LastName</th><th>AgencyName</th><th>is Active</th><th>Edit</th>
                </tr>
                <c:forEach items="${introducerList}" var="i">
                    <tr>
                        <td >${i.id}</td>
                        <td >${i.firstName}</td>
                        <td >${i.lastName}</td>
                        <td>${i.agencyName}</td>
                        <td >${i.active}</td>
                        <td ><a href="editIntroducer?eitdcid=${i.id}">Edit</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>
            </table>
        </div> 

      </td></tr>
    </table>
    </div>

    </td>

     </tr>

    </table>

    </td>
    </tr>


    </table>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/example1.js"></script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

## axample1.js

```
    function getCategoryForSelectedProduct(){
        $('#loading').html('<img src="./resources/img/ajax-loader.gif">');
            $.ajax({
                url : 'dropdown/getCategoryForSelectedProduct',
                method : 'post',
                ContentType : 'json',
                data : {
                    productName : $('#product').val()
                },

                success : function(response) {
                    var options = '';
                    if (response != null) {
                        $(response).each(function(index, value) {
                            options = options + '<option>' + value + '</option>';
                        });
                        $('#category').html(options);
                    }
                    $('#loading').html('');
                },

                error : function(e) {
                    console.log("ERROR: ", e);
                    display(e);
                },
            });
        }
```

## Screenshot of library

```
[Reference Libraries-1][2]
[Reference Libraries-2][3]
[Reference Libraries-3][4]
[Reference Libraries-4][5]



  [1]: https://github.com/shivam091/Spring-MVC-AJAX-Integration/archive/master.zip
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVGzy.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/siSOU.png
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQJ0j.png
  [5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFB8H.png
```

Comment: r u getting any error in console

Comment: Not even when I add,
error : function(e) {
    console.log("ERROR: ", e);
    display(e);
   },

Comment: https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-refactoring-a-jquery-ajax-post-example/

Comment: The example you send me is might work, but that is not the point, I said above that I tested the  $.ajax() function and it work my problem is I don't understand why the attribuite url doesn't get to its method. Thought the syntax is correct